# Problem using Compile together with Eigensystem

Tags: compile

I have been trying to understand what is wrong with this piece of Mathematica code:

```
{A, B} = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, #, Parallelization -> True, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"] & /@ 
  Eigensystem[{{I, 2, 123}, {I, 5, 343}, {123, 34, 34}} + {{2 I, 4, 
      234}, {3 I, 5, 234}, {23, 35, 2}} + {{3, I, 123}, {I, 7, 
      123}, {23, 34, 2}}]
```

Here, I am trying to use Compile in conjunction with Eigensystem to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a sum of 3x3 matrices. I get the following error:

.CompiledFunction:Compiled Expression `something` must be a machine sized integer.

The code runs without issue if I remove the imaginary unit. What is strange is that I can use the code with imaginary numbers if I use 2x2 matrices instead of 3x3. What could be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: There is just no point in trying to compile the library function Eigensystem once again. Also, I do not understand what you actually want to do there. Do you realize that you hand over just constant matrices to `Compile`?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me, although I also do n ot understand what you are trying to do. (`x` is unused; the compiled function return the output of Eigensystem, which, being symbolic numeric expressions, cause the compiled function to revert to external evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should have written a different matrix as a function of "x" in this example. I was just trying to give an example. Sometimes compile works and sometimes it does not work and I do  not know why. I just started learning Mathematica, but from what I understand there is no need to use compile here since Eigensystem is a compiled function anyway, right?